# Changing Ship Method on Fulfillment in SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, suitescript

So, we have a situation where an order gets a fulfillment created, and an outside company actually handles the fulfillment and shipping of the order. Data is exported to them, and for completed orders, that information in imported back in. Sometimes, though, a different carrier is is used than what is anticipated by the people creating the initial orders, so the carrier has to be altered. However, when using SuiteScript, the NetSuite can be a bit unforgiving if you have to change carriers/ship methods. Depending on what needs to change, you can get hit with the following error:

> Error: Switching the shipping method to another carrier is an
>   unsupported operation, because it requires reloading the item
>   fulfillment form for that carrier.

From my experience, this means having to delete the fulfillment, changing the shipping options on the order (which can mess up the existing cost calculations), and then creating a new fulfillment. This route is undesirable as it breaks the chain of data with the 3rd party warehouse. This method is also required as the 3rd party's system doesn't allow for backorders, and trying to manage sending out data for what can be fulfilled from an order prior to creating a fulfillment has turned out to be a nightmare.

For example, this issue comes up because the order taker assumes that the carrier will be UPS and the method will be UPS Freight. The reality may be that the carrier will instead be maybe YRC or Old Dominion, which requires a different record structure. But, it also cannot be assumed it won't be UPS Freight as that is also used by the 3rd party warehouse. They make different carrier choices based on lowest cost to the destination. I think this all comes down to how NetSuite manages something like three or four different package sublists based on carrier/ship method. When you make the change through the UI, it will reload the fulfillment with the necessary changes and you can go from there.

For anyone wanting a code example, this is currently the best example I can provide, which will fail if NetSuite determines the change requires a different package sublist:

```
var recId = 1234;
var shipMethod = 5678;
var ifRec = nlapiLoadRecord("itemfulfillment", recId, { recordmode : "dynamic" });
ifRec.setFieldValue("shipcarrier", "nonups");
ifRec.setFieldValue("shipmethod", shipMethod);
nlapiSubmitRecord(ifRec);
```

I assumed that maybe this could be done with an initialization value when loading the fulfillment, but nothing I've tried seems to be allowed as a value initialization value. My attempts included the following parameters:

- carrierform
- shipcarrier
- shipmethod
- nsi (shows up in the URL when you change the ship carrier/method in the UI)

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found the answer to my problem...

```
nlapiSubmitField("itemfulfillment", fulfillmentId,
    ["carrierform", "shipcarrier", "shipmethod"],
    ["ns", "nonups", shipMethod]
);
```

The values passed in for "carrierform" and "shipcarrier" vary depending on the target ship method. Given that NetSuite has a different "form" depending on if the carrier is UPS, FedEx, USPS, or other, driving which packaging sublist will actually be available on the item fulfillment record, the "carrierform" value will have to be hunted down. I only know that the value is "ups" for UPS shipping, and "ns' for other shipping. I haven't yet found the values for when the FedEx or USPS packaging sublists are being used.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, but I was using Suitescript 2.0 and had to load the record for other reasons and found that as long as you set those fields, you won't get an error and you can set the shipmethod to what you like. My code looked like this...

```
        ifRec.setValue({ fieldId: 'carrierform', value: carrierForm, ignoreFieldChange: false });

        ifRec.setValue({ fieldId: 'shipcarrier', value: shipCarrier, ignoreFieldChange: false });

        ifRec.setValue({ fieldId: 'shipmethod', value: shipMethod, ignoreFieldChange: false });

        ifId = ifRec.save({ enableSourcing: true, ignoreMandatoryFields: true });
```

It works beautifully.

Also, getting the value for the carrierform field isn't difficult. All you have to do is:

1. Open an Item Fulfillment record in edit mode.
2. Open the Developer tools console in the window (f12)
3. From the Shipping Method dropdown on the Item Fulfillment, select the shipping method you want
4. In the console window enter nlapiGetFieldValue('carrierform');
5. Press enter and there you have it!
6. You can also get the field internal ids for the other two fields as well this way